# Delete from multiple tables query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-delete

I want to delete all these results, from this query based on reserveringsnr.

```
(SELECT DISTINCT res.reserveringsnr, datum, begintijd, eindtijd, aantalpersonen, klantnr, betaald, tafr.tafelnr, menr.reserveringsnr, menr.menunr, menr.uniqueid FROM reserveringen as res
    INNER JOIN menus_regel as menr
    ON res.reserveringsnr = menr.reserveringsnr
    INNER JOIN tafels_regel AS tafr
    ON res.reserveringsnr = tafr.reserveringsnr
    WHERE res.reserveringsnr = '21')
```

But something like this doesnt seem to work

```
DELETE FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT res.reserveringsnr, datum, begintijd, eindtijd, aantalpersonen, klantnr, betaald, tafr.tafelnr, menr.reserveringsnr, menr.menunr, menr.uniqueid FROM reserveringen as res
    INNER JOIN menus_regel as menr
    ON res.reserveringsnr = menr.reserveringsnr
    INNER JOIN tafels_regel AS tafr
    ON res.reserveringsnr = tafr.reserveringsnr
    WHERE res.reserveringsnr = '21')Delete
WHERE Delete.reserveringsnr = '21'
```

Anyone could push me a bit in the right direction?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say that you want to "*delete all these results*", do you want to delete the related records from every underlying table or from only some of them?

Comment: `delete from sometable where conditions IN (your select up there)`? note that in mysql you can't update/delete from at able which you're also selecting from.

Comment: In general you can only delete from one table at a time starting with the child tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the query below will delete all records on table `reserveringen` only.

```
DELETE  res
FROM    reserveringen as res
        INNER JOIN menus_regel as menr
            ON res.reserveringsnr = menr.reserveringsnr
        INNER JOIN tafels_regel AS tafr
            ON res.reserveringsnr = tafr.reserveringsnr
WHERE   res.reserveringsnr = '21'
```

but if you want to delete records from all tables where `reserveringsnr` matched up, then you need to specify all table names in `DELETE` clause

```
DELETE  res, menr, tafr
FROM    reserveringen as res
        INNER JOIN menus_regel as menr
            ON res.reserveringsnr = menr.reserveringsnr
        INNER JOIN tafels_regel AS tafr
            ON res.reserveringsnr = tafr.reserveringsnr
WHERE   res.reserveringsnr = '21'
```

Comment: use the second query below.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do it in one line, then @JW's answer looks correct.  However, I have preferred running these in separate lines for performance issues -- if you have lots of records in each table, the joins will take longer than the individual deletes.

```
DELETE 
FROM reserveringen  
WHERE reserveringsnr = '21';

DELETE 
FROM menus_regel 
WHERE reserveringsnr = '21';

DELETE 
FROM tafels_regel 
WHERE reserveringsnr = '21'
```

Here is a useful link on deletes though:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html